Issue with Custom Chain Configuration in Hardhat: Network Not Appearing
I'm trying to add the LineaSepolia network as a custom chain in my Hardhat project. I've configured it in my hardhat.config.js as follows:
{
  network: "lineaSepolia",
  chainId: 59141,
  urls: {
    apiURL: "https://api-sepolia.lineascan.build/",
    browserURL: "https://sepolia.lineascan.build/",
  },
}

However, when I run the command npx hardhat verify --list-networks, the LineaSepolia network doesn't appear in the list. What could be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the custom network configuration is recognized by Hardhat?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
I tried adding a custom network configuration for LineaSepolia in my Hardhat project. And the code snippet I used in my hardhat.config.js

Are you facing any errors when you’re running the deploy command by passing --network lineaSepolia flag at the end?

When you execute this command:
npx hardhat verify --list-networks

lineaSepolia should be shown in the "Custom networks added by you or by plugins:" section like:

Make sure you that you've added the lineaSepolia network details in the networks object of your hardhat.config.js, like:
networks: {
  lineaSepolia: {
    url: process.env.LINEA_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
    accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY],
    chainId: 59141
  },
}

Because, that's what you need for the contract deployment. Then, you can deploy your contract either using hardhat-ignition or hardhat-deploy depending on your requirements, by passing lineaSepolia in the --network flag at the end of the corresponding deployment command.
P.S., You can get the public RPC url for Linea Sepolia network from Chainlist.
Deployment using hardhat-ignition
npx hardhat ignition deploy ./ignition/modules/YourModuleName.js --network lineaSepolia


Deployment using hardhat-deploy (deploy script)
npx hardhat run scripts/YourDeploymentScript.js --network lineaSepolia



For the contract verification, you need the details (as you've mentioned in your question) in the customChains array of the etherscan object, along with the explorer's API key, like:
etherscan: {
  apiKey: {
    lineaSepolia: process.env.LINEASCANSCAN_API_KEY
  },
  customChains: [
    {
      network: "lineaSepolia",
      chainId: 59141,
      urls: {
        apiURL: "https://api-sepolia.lineascan.build/api",
        browserURL: "https://sepolia.lineascan.build",
      },
    }
  ]
}

NOTE: The value of the apiURL that you've mentioned in your question is missing the /api endpoint.
And, you can get the Lineascan API key from the Lineascan Client Portal.
Now, you can verify your deployed contract:
npx hardhat verify ${DEPLOYED_CONTRACT_ADDRESS} ${CONSTRUCTOR_ARG_1} ${CONSTRUCTOR_ARG_2} --network lineaSepolia



Here's the full hardhat.config.js file for reference:
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require("dotenv").config();
/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  networks: {
    lineaSepolia: {
      url: process.env.LINEA_SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [process.env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 59141,
    },
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      lineaSepolia: process.env.LINEASCANSCAN_API_KEY
    },
    customChains: [
      {
        network: "lineaSepolia",
        chainId: 59141,
        urls: {
          apiURL: "https://api-sepolia.lineascan.build/api",
          browserURL: "https://sepolia.lineascan.build",
        },
      }
    ]
  },
  sourcify: {
    enabled: false
  }
};


Thanks a lot,for very detailed explanation.It worked successfully

You're welcome. Happy coding!
